Pandas vs. Polars: mean() function
There's code which counts mean value of a column.
For pandas:
pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, float('inf'), float('inf')]
}).groupby('id').mean()

      a
id     
A   1.5
B   NaN

For Polars:
pl.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
    'a': [1., 2., 3., 4., float('inf'), float('inf')]
}).group_by('id').mean()

┌─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ B   ┆ inf │
│ A   ┆ 1.5 │
└─────┴─────┘

In the first example we have NaN value for ID "B", but for the same ID in the second one we have inf
Why and on what principle do they count differently?
I tried to reproduce Polars example on Pandas, but got stuck with different results in dataframes.

Which pandas version did you use? I have Inf on pandas 2.2.2

I get the same output using the latest version of both libraries. The only case which triggers a NaN is having a mix of -Inf and +Inf (as expected since addition of -Inf and +Inf is undefined):
data = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, float('inf'), float('inf'), 1, float('-inf'), 1, float('inf'), float('-inf')]}
print(f'pandas {pd.__version__}:', pd.DataFrame(data).groupby('id').mean(), '', sep='\n')
print(f'polars {pl.__version__}:', pl.DataFrame(data).group_by('id', maintain_order=True).mean(), '', sep='\n')

Output:
pandas 2.2.2:
      a
id     
A   1.5
B   inf
C  -inf
D   NaN

polars 0.20.26:
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ a    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ A   ┆ 1.5  │
│ B   ┆ inf  │
│ C   ┆ -inf │
│ D   ┆ NaN  │
└─────┴──────┘


When calculating the mean with pandas, if a group contains float('inf') and finite values, it results in nan to indicate an undefined result, while when calculating the mean in polars, if a group contains only float('inf') values, it results in inf. If there are finite values mixed with inf, it results in nan. I you want to reproduce the behaviour of polars in pandas you can do this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def custom_mean(series):
    if np.any(np.isinf(series)):
        return float('inf')
    else:
        return series.mean()

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, float('inf'), float('inf')]})
result = df.groupby('id').agg({'a': custom_mean})
print(result)

which gives
      a
id     
A   1.5
B   inf


Which pandas version did you use? I can't reproduce this.

Also the function seems incorrect, you'd need to use any, not all and this wouldn't correctly handle -inf, nor a mix of -inf/+inf.

@mozway You are right. I corrected it.
